# Gage-Grayson-Hamilton curve-shortening flow, at an angle

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, flows

The Gage-Grayson-Hamilton [curve-shortening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve-shortening_flow) flows along the normal to the curve:

---

[image: CurveShortening]

          

<sup>(Image from [Andrejs Treibergs presentation PDF](http://www.math.utah.edu/~treiberg/CurvFlowSlides.pdf).)</sup>

---

The result is remarkable avoidance of self-intersection, regardless
of how convoluted is the original curve, and
ultimate convergence to a "round point."
See, e.g., this
[YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHfpacPLHIA).

My question is:

> ***Q***. Has this flow been studied along vectors at some fixed angle to the normal?
>   E.g., at $90^\circ$ counterclockwise of the normal, tangent to the curve?

Presumably, for any angle $\alpha > 0$ counterclockwise of the normal,
the curve might self-intersect during its evolution.
But perhaps it still converges to a limit shape?

Comment: In this generalization it seems that a circle would just "rotate".  Would you consider this case also as having converged to a limit shape?

Comment: @Menachem: Yes, exactly, the circle remains a circle; let's call that its limit shape. The question is: What happens to other shapes, both for $\alpha=90^\circ$, and for arbitrary fixed $\alpha$?

Comment: FYI: A curve shortening flow toy by Anthony [here](http://a.carapetis.com/csf/). Also, the flow is along the curvature vector $\kappa n$ instead of the normal $n$.

Comment: The flow is not yet defined: What is its speed?

Comment: @FanZheng: Good point. I would be interested to learn of work exploring any speed along a vector at a constant angle to the normal.

Comment: It has always been my intuition that _movement in the direction of the tangent only affect the parametrization not the embedding_, so projecting your speed vector to its normal part should not change the shape of the evolution. If I find the time I'll try to make it rigorous and post it as an answer.

Comment: If $\partial_t \gamma = -k n + v t$ with $\gamma : \mathbb{S}^1 \times (0, T) \to \mathbb{R}^2$, then letting $\phi : \mathbb{S}^1 \times (0, T) \to \mathbb{S}^1$ satisfy $\partial_t \phi = - v \circ \phi$ you find that $\bar{\gamma}(x, t) = \gamma(\phi(x, t), t)$ satisfies $\partial_t \bar{\gamma} = -\bar{k} \bar{n}$.

Comment: This paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.1617 may be helpful.

Comment: @PaulBryan: Thanks for the pointer to "Self-similar solutions to the curve shortening flow."

Comment: your welcome :)